# Accessing static variable using OGNL in Struts2

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, ognl

Good day!

I am reading Manning's struts2 book and one of the topic is accessing the static variable using OGNL using the syntax  `@[fullClassName]@[property or methodCall]`

so I tried it on my program and my code is as follows:

BEAN:

```
public class ContactsBean {

    private static int count = 1;
    //getter and setter
}
```

ACTION:

```
private ContactsBean contacts;
//getters and setters
```

JSP:

```
   <s:property value="@com.demo.bean.ContactsBean@count" />

or
    <s:property value="@vs@count" />  //valuestack method
```

but it doesn't work. Am i missing something?
Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> @see **[OGNL Basics : Accessing static properties](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-Accessingstaticproperties)**

**BEAN** :

```
public class ContactsBean {
    private static int count = 1; 

    // static getter
    // setter
}
```

```
<s:property value="@com.demo.bean.ContactsBean@getCount()" />
```

---

**other case**

```
public class ContactsBean {
    public static final int SCALE = 50;
}
```

```
<s:property value="@com.demo.bean.ContactsBean@SCALE" />
```

Comment: The new link is: https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl-basics.html

Answer (score 3):

Apache Struts 2 Documentation - struts.properties
http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/strutsproperties.html

To enable static method access / invocation set the Struts2 constant in your struts.properties file in your base package:

```
struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess=true
```

.. or I believe you can set it in the struts.xml as

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its work fine if we mentioned the below entry in struts.xml

```
  <constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in new release of struts 2 (2.3.20), this (`struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess`)  will be removed soon from struts.

Please review [Struts 2 refactoring code to avoid OGNL static method access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018861/struts-2-refactoring-code-to-avoid-ognl-static-method-access) to find out how you can still use this feature in new version.