# How to set a value in application scope in struts2?

Tags: struts

I have a list that is accessible to all user of my application.I am currently adding it to session of a particular user.But i want it to be in application scope rather than session scope.Please help also provide reference/link to any example

Comment: If you are using Struts2, declare your static list in a class and access it through static reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906629/accessing-static-variable-using-ognl-in-struts2

Comment: thank for reply
is there another way something like aplication context?

Comment: If you refer to a static item from a Class, it will be same throughout the application, right?

Comment: i know about static item i was asking about application context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you want to use the list: you want to display that list to the screen or you just need it as configuration. To display it you could:

- create your list `statically` in your Action, then display it in the JSP
- you could take the list `dynamically` from a database, then display it in the JSP

To use it as configuration: some data can be made available at application level at initialization, but those are configuration params. More info here:

- [where to put configuration parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287082/best-practice-where-do-i-put-configuration-parameters-for-my-own-application-in)

Using the `ServletContext` is the only way you can **set parameters dynamically** to the servlet **from your code**: `servletContext.setAttribute()`. More info here:

- [why use servlet context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046717/why-use-servletcontext-setattribute)

Answer (score 4):

In action you can use :

```
ServletActionContext.getContext().getApplication().put("myVar", myObj);
```

In order to set in a JSP, you can use the [`<s:set>`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/set.html) tag as :

`<s:set name="myVar" scope="application" value="myObj"/>`